# How to get Names of Firewall rules by InstanceID addressing particular port

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to identify all firewall rules, which are addressing particular port.
Here is how I can do it manually:

```
Get-NetFirewallPortFilter | Where { $_.LocalPort -Eq "RPC" } `
| Format-Table -Property InstanceID
```

Now I need to know the name of a rule:

```
Show-NetFirewallRule | Where { $_.InstanceID –Eq “Netlogon-TCP-RPC-In”} `
| Format-Table -Property DisplayName
```

Then I get:

```
DisplayName
-----------
Netlogon Service Authz (RPC)
```

I do not want to do it manually
I've tried following script to get the list of names:

```
$InstanceIDs = Get-NetFirewallPortFilter | Where { $_.LocalPort -Eq "RPC" } `
| Format-Table -Property InstanceID
foreach ($InstanceID in $InstanceIDs)
{
    Show-NetFirewallRule | Where { $_.InstanceID –Eq $InstanceID} `
    | Format-Table -Property DisplayName
}
```

Got nothing at this point.
Figured out that `InstanceID` within `$InstanceIDs` is not a string, but failed to convert it.

Any idea on how make it working?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue has something to do with `$InstanceID` *type* (try `$InstanceID.Gettype()` in your script). Next code snippet could help:

```
$InstanceIDs =  -split $( 
    Get-NetFirewallPortFilter | 
        Where { $_.LocalPort -Eq "RPC" } | 
            Format-Table -Property InstanceID -HideTableHeaders | 
                Out-String
    )

Show-NetFirewallRule | 
    Where { $_.InstanceID –In $InstanceIDs} |
        ForEach-Object { 
            if ($_.Name) {
                "{0} {1} {2}" -f $_.Name, '==', $_.DisplayName
            }
        }
```

Note that `$InstanceIDs` is an array of strings in above code snippet; moreover, `$_.Name` property in `Show-NetFirewallRule` corresponds to `InstanceID` one in `Get-NetFirewallPortFilter`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I knew the problem was with type, just did not know how to convert it.